# LoginToboggan is not assigning new roles after validating email

Tags: authentication-authorization

LoginToboggan is not assigning new roles after validating the email. I've changed the token as it was in https://www.drupal.org/node/2003778 discussion. Now I'm getting: "Sorry, you can only use your validation link once for security reasons." error ,message if the user logged in.

even after clicking the link, if I logged out, it giving me the error "Sorry, you can only use your validation link once for security reasons. Please log in with your username and password instead now."

If I use my normal login details, it give me access but not assigning to the role I should.

Am I missing any settings/token perhaps?

I'm not a programmer, please make your ans details.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of LoginToboggan and Drupal are you using?